# Updating GMap.NET Markers in C#

Tags: c#, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, gmap.net

I need to update my GMap.NET Markers in C#.
I added my markers like below:

```
GMap.NET.WindowsForms.GMapMarker marker2 =
                new GMap.NET.WindowsForms.Markers.GMarkerGoogle(
                    new GMap.NET.PointLatLng(39.81750, 30.52686),
                    new Bitmap("hello.png"));
            marker2.ToolTipText = "Hello";
            marker2.ToolTip.Fill = Brushes.Black;
            marker2.ToolTip.Foreground = Brushes.White;
            marker2.ToolTip.Stroke = Pens.Black;
            markers.Markers.Add(marker2);
            gMapControl1.Overlays.Add(markers);
```

I want to update this marker's position in a timer.
How can i change this variable in a timer thread?
Do i need to make these markers global variables?
Thanks for answers.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to pass the overlay into the timer:

```
System.Timers.Timer t = new System.Timers.Timer();
GMapOverlay overlay_ = new GMapOverlay();
//do stuff to your overlay
t.Elapsed += (sender, e) => MyElapsedMethod(sender, e, overlay_);
```

Your overlays are all references so you can simply update the markers and it should update on the map (assuming you have added it to the gmapcontrol):

```
static void MyElapsedMethod(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e, GMapOverlay overlay) 
{
     overlay.Markers[..].Position = new PointLatLng(0,0); //for your new position
}
```

I have not tested this code, but I have good success doing something similar using a background worker.

Comment: OK. And how can i change the markers variables in the same context of above code?

Comment: i want to be able to call the markers as a variable and change them. I am declaring them as above but can't reach them as a variable. I have little knowledge in c#. Sorry for my question.

Comment: You will need to populate a `List` of markers, you can use the `Tag` property to tell them apart, just pass it an unique arbitrary ID. Then filter the markers list for that id and update the position. IMO you don't need to pass the list or the overlay to the timer, just hold them in a field.

Comment: Your markers are available as a list, so you just need to use    overlay.Markers[0].Position = new PointLatLng(0,0); assuming you are wanting to change the marker at index 0. If you have only added one marker, as you have done in your sample code, then you would use index 0.

Comment: @JAlecksen your way works perfectly. now i just need to make this overlay and markers declared as globally (public).